# added custom fields not showing up in thank you page billing address section in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

In checkout page i had added extra fields but it is not showing up in billing address section in Thank you page.Nobody has answered this question.i added extra field like area in checkout page.i want to display it in billing_address in Thank you page.how to do it.

Comment: We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you have added the extra fields in the billing section as described over here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-6

So now, you can use the 'woocommerce_thankyou' hook to display the value of fields.

Something like this:

```
<?PHP
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'show_data_on_thankyou_page', 20 );

function show_data_on_thankyou_page( $order_id ){  ?>
    <section class="custom-billing-details">
        <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--nif"><span>NIF: </span><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_nif', true ); ?></p>
    </section>
<?PHP 
}
?>
```

Comment: i want to display it in billing along with default fields in billing address section in thank you page

Comment: Alright, the entire billing section is coming from the "order-details-customer.php" template so you have to place the same template in your theme folder and modify it accordingly. The template file is located here: woocommerce/templates/order-details-customer.php